# How can I access JSON.@attribute from an XML Converted on Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json

I got a JSON converted from XML.

So, how can I get `json.@attribute.something`.

`@` <-- this one will make javascript error

I use Javascript.

Comment: U can try a converter, which gives you only elements and no attributes. So Elements and Attributes in XMl get converted ONLY to Elements in Json.

Comment: You're right, I changed to jQUery, and it auto converted JSON to an Object. So I just use JSON["@attribute"] and it work :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a great exercise of imagination, I suppose you've used jQuery to download some JSON through AJAX and you have an object with a key called "@attribute", such as this:

```
var foo = {
    "@attribute": 33
}
```

You just need to use square brackets:

```
console.log(foo["@attribute"])
```

Comment: Oh la la! Thank you! I just use JSON as an array , json["@attritube"] and it work. I love you! U saved my day!

Comment: Being picky: 1) At this point, you no longer have a JSON string since jQuery already parsed it for you and converted it into an object 2) JavaScript arrays don't allow alphanumeric keys `;-P` Glad I helped.